# How to determine whether a script is run at startup or manually?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

By having a script located in a subfolder `startup scripts` of e.g. the user script folder, one can have a script run at startup. What I would like to achieve now is having the script determine whether it is run due to that startup (and e.g. create menu items for its functions) or whether it was run manually (and then perform its main function, not caring about its startup function). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the script is located within the Startup Scripts Folder:

```js
var scriptKind = (app.activeScript.parent.name=="Startup Scripts")? "startup":"normal";
alert( scriptKind );
```

Comment: Ah. Just checking the folder. Awesome. I was thinking about creating a targetengine and have a global flag that gets set on startup. But this is much simpler. 

Comment: Sounds like I've been overthinking this m-/ Of course I can then symlink the same script both in the startup and regular folder... Though @fabiantheblind's idea also makes sense, especially since for not recreating menus you need to keep track somehow anyway...

Comment: Simple yet possibly wrong if script is placed as shortcut or inside subfolder. So it's very contextual.

Comment: Indeed, e.g. it turns out `app.activeScript` returns the real script location when a Windows `.lnk` is used... In that case I'll have to stick to @fabiantheblind's suggestion

Comment: You also have access to $.fileName that returns the full path of the current script if saved.